# Replace new lines in CLXML file

Tags: powershell

After generating a CLXML file:

```
[string]$myString = 'foobar' | Export-Clixml -Path C:\Files\test.clxml
```

I'm trying to remove line breaks after the right close anchor `>`. I have tried:

```
(Get-Content C:\Files\test.clxml) -replace "`n", "" | Set-Content C:\Files\test.clxml
```

Also tried using `-replace r` but this strips out `r` characters from the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that in your test there are no newlines to replace. `Get-Content` is returning a string *array* that is seen as having newlines on screen when rendered. To actually get them inside the string to be manipulated try one of these.

```
(Get-Content C:\Files\test.clxml -Raw) -replace "`n" | Set-Content C:\Files\test.clxml
(Get-Content C:\Files\test.clxml | Out-String) -replace "`n" | Set-Content C:\Files\test.clxml
```

The latter would be needed if your have PS Version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` returns an *array* holding each single line (not containing any line feeds).

`Set-Content` writes your array of lines to a single file separating them with line feeds.

Meaning you should do the following to get what you want:

```
(Get-Content C:\Files\test.clxml) -join "" | Set-Content C:\Files\test.clxml
```